# jQuery ajax (JSON) get array from PHP works fine, but doesn't on webserver

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

I found some similar questions, but no solution has solved this problem.

```
function loadProject(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadDrumsetData.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            i: id
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (e) {
            pushLoadedData(e.bank); //create the JavaScript array
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

I try to get the array result from `loadDrumsetData.php`.
On my local apache it works fine.
But on my webserver (apache) I get this parser error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

**The loadDrumsetData.php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(-1);

$i=$_GET["i"];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userxxx","xxxxx","drumpcdata");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM `session_".$i."` ORDER BY `pID` ASC ");

$soundArray = array();
$bankArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $pid = $row['pID'];
    $r = $row['Row'];
    $sound = $row['Sound'];
    $number = $row['Number'];
    $x = $row['X'];
    $y = $row['Y'];
    $w = $row['W'];
    $h = $row['H'];
    $spr = $row['Sprite'];
    $pressed = $row['Pressed'];
    $bankArray = [];
    array_push($soundArray, [$pid, $r, $sound ,$number,$x,$y,$w,$h,$spr, $pressed]);
    array_push($bankArray, $soundArray);
  }

mysqli_close($con);

$encoded = json_encode(array("bank" => $bankArray));
echo $encoded; 
?>
```

I would appreciate any help on this topic. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Can you show us the returned JSON? If you have a look at the server response, it should be quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are connecting to mysql database correctly?

First this **does not stop processing** if connection fails:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

And tries to do queries etc...

Since on failure, your Server sends strings instead of json,
It will blow things up.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo json_encode(
            array(
                "Success" => false,
                "Reason" => "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error()
            )
        );
   exit(0);
}
```

Please try adding some failure control to your scripts.

Query may fail too.

Comment: the connection to the MySQL database works. I include it on the Web server from separate PHP file. This works in other places, for example When uploading data.

Comment: Can you please show us what do you expect as the output and what do you get?

Comment: i want to get data from MySql table to PHP array, to rebuild with this a earlier saved JavaScript array.
saving the data in MySql database works fine. but when loading, i get only this output: 

   Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"} parsererror
   SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
   parsererror

return window.JSON.parse( data );

when i try to load or save on my local apache server (wamp), all works fine.

Comment: Please look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , it says 'json' for instance not 'JSON' check your ajax jQuery...